# Self Referencing Entities not nullable

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, code-first

in may case i want use this Person class and it's not nullable property called RelatedPerson in ef code first:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    // ... other properties

    [Required]
    public virtual Person RelatedPerson { get; set; }
}
```

now, how could i add mapping to define this relation and for first record as root of Pesron table the Id is one.

Comment: Your last sentence is not clear. Could you try to use some other words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add a `RequiredAttribute` to a self-referencing property. It would not validate for the root entity which does not have a RelatedPerson.

You can enforce it to be required via business logic in Save and Update functions.